# JAGS & R: Storing results of matrix multiplication product in 3 dimensional array

Tags: r, arrays, matrix-multiplication, jags

I am running a hierarchical Bayesian model in JAGS from R and am writing my likelihood functions by defining four different matrices, then using matrix multiplication to get my full likelihood for each scenario. To be more specific (if it helps at all), I have a state-space multievent mark-recapture model, and each matrix is a state transition, but there are 4 transitions that need to be accounted for. I have a model running that works great, but now I want to add time-dependence to my model and thus I want each of my four matrices to have a third dimension (time). My question is, how do I conduct matrix multiplication within my JAGS model specification on these 3-D arrays and store the resulting set of matrices in a 3-D array.

In my original model, I define each matrix like this (not my real matrices or dimensions):

```
  model {  #begin JAGS model specification

    px1[1,1:4]<-c(phiA,0,0,1-phiA)
    px1[2,1:4]<-c(0,phiA,0,1-phiA)
    px1[3,1:4]<-c(0,0,phiA,1-phiA)
    px1[4,1:4]<-c(0,0,0,1)
    
    px2[1,1:5]<-c(...)
    ##more code here
    px2[4,1:5]<-c(...)
    
    px3[1,1:4]<-c(...)
    ##more code here
    px3[5,1:4]<-c(...)
    
    px <- px1 %*% px2 %*% px3  ##define final matrix using matrix multiplication

    #more JAGS model specification code here
  } #JAGS model
```

That all works fine, but now, I want to have a different matrix for each time step. So I set my matrices up like this:

```
model {     #begin JAGS model specification
    
    for (t in 1:yrs) {
       px1[1,1:4,t]<-c(phiA[t],0,0,1-phiA[t])
       px1[2,1:4,t]<-c(0,phiA[t],0,1-phiA[t])
       ##more code here to finish defining px1 matrix...
    
       px2[1,1:5,t]<-c(...)
       ###more code here to finish px2 matrix...
    
       px3[1,1:4,t]<-c(...)
       ##more code here to finish px3...
    } #t

    # more JAGS code here
  } #JAGS model
```

But how do I conduct the matrix multiplication within the JAGS model specification such that I get a final matrix `(px1 %*% px2 %*% px3)`  for each time-step? I've tried various options, but cannot get any of them to work in JAGS. Here are some of the things I've tried:

First Try:

```
  model {
    #...JAGS code
    for (t in 1:yrs) {
      #[define 3-D matrices here as above]
    
      px[,,t]<-px1[,,t] %*% px2[,,t] %*% px3[,,t]
     } #t

    # more JAGS code...
  } #JAGS model
```

Second try:

```
    for (t in 1:yrs) {
      #[define 3-D matrices here as above]
    
      px[1:4,1:4,t]<-px1[1:4,1:4,t] %*% px2[1:4,1:5,t] %*% px3[1:5,1:4,t]
    } #t
```

Third try:

```
    for (t in 1:yrs) {
      #[define matrix 3-D px1 matrix as above]
      px1.tmp[1:4,1:4]<-px1[,,t]  #store first 2 dimensions in temporary matrix
    
      #[define matrix 2 as above]
      px2.tmp[1:4,1:5]<-px2[,,t]
    
      #[define matrix 3 as above]
      px3.tmp[1:5,1:4]<-px3[,,t]
    
      px.tmp<-px1.tmp %*% px2.tmp %*% px3.tmp
    
      px[,,t]<-px.tmp
    }
```

I've tried other variations on those basic themes, including setting up the final px array  outside of the JAGS model definition.

```
    model {
      #JAGS model code here...
    } #end JAGS model code

    px<-array(dim=c(4,4,Years)
```

I get slightly different errors depending on my approach, but they all center around the matrix multiplication operation. For the third try + defining the px array outside the model definition, I got the following error

```
>RUNTIME ERROR:
>Compilation error on line 1021.
>Cannot evaluate subset expression for px
```

Line 1021 is the matrix multiplication line in the jags file.

I would appreciate any help on this, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that `calc` is your function that calculates the matricial product you can `lapply` the years to it and use the `abind::abind` function to bind the resulting list items into the 3-D array.

```
library(abind)


phiA <- seq(0,1,.01)
calc <- function(t) {
    px1<-array(dim=c(4,4))
    px2<-array(dim=c(4,4))
    px3<-array(dim=c(4,4))
    px1[1,1:4]<-c(phiA[t],0,0,1-phiA[t])
    px1[2,1:4]<-c(0,phiA[t],0,1-phiA[t])
    px1[3,1:4]<-c(0,0,phiA[t],1-phiA[t])
    px1[4,1:4]<-c(0,0,0,1)
    
    px2[4,1:4]<-c(phiA[t],0,0,1-phiA[t])
    px2[1,1:4]<-c(0,phiA[t],0,1-phiA[t])
    px2[2,1:4]<-c(0,0,phiA[t],1-phiA[t])
    px2[3,1:4]<-c(0,0,0,1)
    
    px3[2,1:4]<-c(phiA[t],0,0,1-phiA[t])
    px3[1,1:4]<-c(0,phiA[t],0,1-phiA[t])
    px3[4,1:4]<-c(0,0,phiA[t],1-phiA[t])
    px3[3,1:4]<-c(0,0,0,1)
    px1 %*%  px2 %*%  px3
}

abind(lapply(1:length(phiA), calc), along=3)
```

Comment: The solution has to work in JAGS (i.e., in the BUGS language), so I don't think this will work for my problem.

Comment: @Gina aren't u using R

Comment: Yes, I am using R, but the code I'm having trouble with sits inside my JAGS model specification block, which has to be in BUGS language. That was not very clear in my original question. I have modified my question to make that more explicit.